# How can I make my C editor support Intellij keymap?

Tags: c, ide, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, codelite

I'm used to the keyboard shortcuts used in JetBrains products such as Intellij IDEA and PyCharm.

I'm now using CodeLite to work on C code, and it's really annoying that the keyboard shortcuts are different.

Is there a way to make CodeLite support pretty-much the same key-mapping as PyCharm? If not, what C editor (apart from the paid-for CLion) supports this?

Answer (score 0):

CodeLite has no builtin maps (I might consider this as a feature request if you will open one here: https://github.com/eranif/codelite/new)

You can change the current default keyboard bindings from the main menu bar:

`Settings->Keyboard Shortcuts`

Just type in the search box the description you want to change, for example:
If you will type `build` you will get list of all actions associated with the `build` keyword, double click one and you will open the `edit` dialog.

[image]

HTH,
Eran